# Implementation of Depth-First-Search on a permutation tree in Python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, permutation, depth-first-search

I have a quadratic Matrix of size n, say A, with non-negative real entries a_ij.
Furthermore I have a permutation tree. For n = 3 it looks like this: [image: Permutation tree n = 3].

Now I would like to do a Depth-search (I don't know really, whether "Depth-search" is the correct description for this, but let's use it for now) along the branches of the tree in the following way:

On the first partial tree on the very left do the following starting with an "empty" Permutation (x,x,x):

If a_12 > a_21 set (1,2,x) and then check whether a_23 > a_32. If this is true as well, save (1,2,3) in a list, say P. Then go back to the first Level and check whether a_13 > a_31 and so on.
If a_21 > a_12 or a_32 > a_23 do not save the Permutation in P and go back to the first Level and check whether a_13 > a_31. If this is true set (1,3,x) and then check whether a_23 > a_32. If this is true save (1,3,2) in P and continue with the next partial tree. If a_31 > a_13 or a_32 > a_23 do not save the Permutation in P and continue with the same procedure for the next partial tree.

This procedure/algorithm I would like to implement for an arbitrary  natural n > 0 with Input just the Matrix A and n and as an Output all permutations of size n that fullfill these conditions. By now I am not able to implement this in a general way.

Preferably in Python, but Pseudo Code would be nice as well. I also want to avoid functions like "itertools Permutation", because in the use case I Need to apply this for large n, for example n = 100, and then itertools Permutation is very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should get you what you want:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations

def fluboxing_permutations(a, n):
    return [p for p in permutations(range(n))
        if all(a[i, j] > a[j, i] for i, j in zip(p, p[1:]))]

n = 3
a = np.random.random([n, n])
fluboxing_permutations(a, n)
```

`itertools.permutations` will yield permutations in lexicographical order, which corresponds to your tree; then we check that for each consecutive pair of indices in the permutation, the element in the matrix is greater than the element at swapped indices. If so, we retain the permutation.

(No idea how to describe what the function does, so I made a new name. Hope you like it. If anyone knows a better way to describe it, please edit! :P )

**EDIT:** Here's a recursive function that should do the same, but with pruning:

```
def fluboxing_permutations_r(a, n):
    nset = set(range(n))
    def inner(p):
        l = len(p)
        if l > 1 and a[p[-2]][p[-1]] <= a[p[-1]][p[-2]]:
            return []
        if l == n:
            return [p]
        return [r for i in nset - set(p)
                for r in inner(p + (i,))]
    return inner(())
```

`p` starts as empty tuple, but it grows in recursion. Once there's at least two elements in the partial permutation, we can test the last two elements and see if it fails the test, and reject it if it does (pruning its subtree out of the search space). If it is a full permutation that wasn't rejected, we return it. If it's not full yet, we append to it all possible indices that are not already in there, and recurse.

**tinyEDIT:** BTW, parameter `n` is kind of redundant, because `n = len(a)` at the top of the function should take care of it.

Comment: Yes, that gives the desired Output, thank you. However I would like to implement this without using "itertools Permutation",since I Need to apply it in the use case for large n, for example n=100, and then itertools permutations is very slow.

Comment: Ah. Let me disagree a little bit - `itertools.permutations` is faster at its job than anything you could write short of making your own C extension. However, true - you can't really prune to optimise the search space.